# How to store data | MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am a beginner at MERN Stack. I can create and save users from Postman
API, but I want users to register independently, and navigate the Login page. What will I do?

I am trying to create Register.jsx to save, but data cannot be saved :(

(I remove the style element because I cannot post my question)

Register.jsx (from Client side)

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { mobile } from "../responsive";

const Container = styled.div``;

const Wrapper = styled.div``;

const Title = styled.h1``;

const Form = styled.form``;

const Input = styled.input``;

const Agreement = styled.span` `;

const Button = styled.button``;

const Register = () => {
  const[user, setUser] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const navigate  = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = e => {
    const {name,value} = e.target;
    
    setUser({...user, [name]:value});
  };

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, email, password } = user;
    const res = await fetch("/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name, email, password
      })
    });
    const data = await res.json();

    if(res.status === 500 || !data){
      window.alert("Invalid Registration");
      console.log("Invalid Registration");
    } else {
      window.alert("Registration Successfull");
      console.log("Registration Successfull");
      navigate("/login");
    }
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <Wrapper>
        <Title>CREATE AN ACCOUNT</Title>
        <Form method="POST">
          <Input 
            placeholder="username" 
            type="text"
            name="username"
            value={user.username}
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <Input placeholder="email" 
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={user.email}
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <Input placeholder="password" 
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={user.password}
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <Button onClick={handleClick}>CREATE</Button>
        </Form>
      </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  );
};
export default Register;
```

auth.js (server-side)

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      req.body.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    ).toString(),
  });
  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why are you encrypting passwords? That won't make them more secure. A hacker can just decrypt them. Instead you should hash them. You're basically storing them as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the full address!

```
 const handleClick = async (e) => {
...
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:<PORT>/register",{...})
...
```